# Initialing django field from __init__

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form:

```
class MatchForm(forms.Form):
    base_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select)

   def __init__(self ,*args, **kwargs):
     BASE_FIELDS = (
                     ('job','JOB'),
                     ('car','CAR'),
     )
     super(MatchForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['base_field'].choices = BASE_FIELDS
```

with this class that I have written, there is no any option in select. How can I insert `BASE_FIELDS`
in `base_field` field.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use forms.ChoiceField? Also the BASE_FIELDS tuple is not closed.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please answer question for check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BASE_FIELDS = (
    ('job','JOB'),
    ('car','CAR'),
)

class MatchForm(forms.Form):
    base_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BASE_FIELDS)
```